# Drawing an open circuit using circuitikz

Tags: packages, circuitikz

Is it possible to draw open circuits using circuitikz like these below?

[image: Examples]

Thank you.

Comment: The answer to your question is definitely yes. If you search TeX.SX you can find many examples using the [circuitikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz) package -- or you could just try reading the manual. This said, some people take exception to questions of the form "Please draw this for me". You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: This is not your first question and you've posted code in questions about PGF/Ti*k*Z before, so it is difficult to believe that you don't have any idea where to start - as opposed to just wanting somebody else to do the work - and especially given you've tagged the question with a relevant package. The literal answer to your question is, of course, simply 'yes'.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.‏‏‏ ‏‏ ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏